# How do i disable the Elevated button when the Image.Network (from firebase) is null

Tags: flutter, image, firebase-storage

I have an Elevated Button, which will save data into the firebase. I want to disable this button when the Image.Network is null.

But somehow when i delete the button, the Elevated button is not getting disabled. Just for your info, the image is coming from Firebase Storage Can someone help.

```
// Here are the codes.....   
 
    // Select and image from the gallery or take a picture with the camera
    // Then upload to Firebase Storage
      Future<void> _upload(String inputSource) async {
        final picker = ImagePicker();
    
        try {
          pickedImage = (await picker.pickImage(
              source: inputSource == 'camera'
                  ? ImageSource.camera
                  : ImageSource.gallery,
              maxWidth: 1920));
    
          final String fileName = path.basename(pickedImage!.path);
          File imageFile = File(pickedImage!.path);
    
          try {
            // Uploading the selected image
    
            await FirebaseStorage.instance
                .ref(widget.value2)
                .child(widget.value4)
                .child(widget.value5)
                .child(fileName)
                .putFile(
                    imageFile,
                    SettableMetadata(customMetadata: {
                      'Station': widget.value2,
                      'Facility': widget.value4,
                      'Item': widget.value5,
                    }));
    
            // Refresh the UI
            setState(() {});
          } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
            if (kDebugMode) {
              debugPrint(error.toString());
            }
          }
        } catch (err) {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            debugPrint(err.toString());
          }
        }
      }
    
      // Retrieve the uploaded images
      // This function is called when the app launches for the first time or when an image is uploaded or deleted
    
      Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> _loadImages() async {
        List<Map<String, dynamic>> files = [];
    
        final ListResult result = await FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref(widget.value2)
            .child(widget.value4)
            .child(widget.value5)
            .list();
        final List<Reference> allFiles = result.items;
    
        await Future.forEach<Reference>(allFiles, (file) async {
          final String fileUrl = await file.getDownloadURL();
          final FullMetadata fileMeta = await file.getMetadata();
          files.add({
            'url': fileUrl,
            'path': file.fullPath,
            'Facility': fileMeta.customMetadata?['Facility'] ?? 'Nobody',
          });
        });
    
        return files;
      }
    
      Future<void> _delete(String ref) async {
        await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(ref).delete();
        setState(() {});
      }
    
    //To display the image
    
     Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Flexible(
                                            child: FutureBuilder(
                                              future: _loadImages(),
                                              builder: (context,
                                                  AsyncSnapshot<
                                                          List<
                                                              Map<String, dynamic>>>
                                                      snapshot) {
                                                if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                                    ConnectionState.done) {
                                                  return ListView.builder(
                                                    itemExtent: 320,
                                                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                                    itemCount:
                                                        snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                      //final Map<String, dynamic>
                                                      image = snapshot.data![index];
    
                                                      return Column(
                                                        children: [
                                                          Image.network(
                                                            image?['url'],
                                                            width: 300,
                                                            height: 250,
                                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                          ),
                                                          const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                                          //Text (
                                                              //image?['Facility']
                                                          //),
    
                                                          IconButton(
                                                            onPressed: () =>
                                                                _delete(
                                                                    image?['path']),
                                                            icon: const Icon(
                                                              Icons.delete,
                                                              color: Colors.red,
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      );
                                                    },
                                                  );
                                                }
    
                                                return const Center(
                                                  child:
                                                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                                );
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )

//Here is the code for the Elevated Button: -
    
    Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                        child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                                          label: const Text('Save'),
                                          icon: const Icon(Icons.save_alt_rounded),
                                          onPressed: (functionality <= 99.0 &&
                                                      image != null)
                                              || (functionality == 100.0 && comments == '')
                                              ? () async {
                                                  final uploadData = {
                                                    'Project': widget.value1,
                                                    'Station': widget.value2,
                                                    'Name': widget.value3,
                                                    'Facility': widget.value4,
                                                    'Item': widget.value5,
                                                    'DateTime': dateTimeEsc,
                                                    'Total In Service':
                                                        totalInService,
                                                    'Functionality (%)':
                                                        functionality,
                                                  };
                                                  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                      .collection('KGL')
                                                      .doc(widget.value2 +
                                                          '_' +
                                                          widget.value4 +
                                                          '_' +
                                                          widget.value5)
                                                      .update(uploadData);
    
                                                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                                      context,
                                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                                          builder: (BuildContext
                                                                  context) =>
                                                              super.widget));
                                                }
                                              : null,
                                        )),
```

[image]

Comment: to be honest i tried my best to understand what does you need as exactly but i fail  . can you hit the required need in other word ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the brief description to the issue. What i am trying to accomplish is that, the elevated button should be enabled and functionable when (functionality <= 99.0 && image != null) || (functionality == 100.0 && comments == ''). The issue is that when the image is null, the button is still enabled and functionable when the image == null. The image is taken from the Image.Network function, from the firebase. My question is that why the app is not sensing the presence of the image (image != null and image ==null)?

Comment: elevated button will never do it it's self ,, you must prevent it programmatically by creating bool value and so chick your null need IF OR {...} , remember you could put null value like onPress : null instead of onPress  : (){}

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you try to accomplish?

Feel free to comment if it doesn't work.

```dart
IconButton(
   onPressed: () {
       if(image?['url'] != ''){
           _delete(image?['path']),
       }
    },
    icon: const Icon(
        Icons.delete,
        color: Colors.red,
       ),
    ),
```